# About registering low cost green patents in the UK

Tags: uk

I have one idea which is about using the uber model in waste management and ... (Question updated !!!)

This idea claims it could achieve many new improvements in society, such as accessing the international waste market size, encouraging society to do recycling and, finally, if it is done by procedure and steps, it could improve democracy to open source community similar to open government tries in California, which could be a multi nationality company form of usa open government samples.

I have published some parts of this project on the internet and some parts are not published, because I am trying to register an environmental or green patent to save the share and attempts of the friends who were involved in this project.

So I am trying to find a low cost and eligible patent registration program for the first registration of this idea and I guess the uk programs are, so low cost (around 160 £). But I have asked here to get some comments about the available green patent registration options in uk to do it faster and with lower cost.

If possible, I would be happy to have some comments about finding some NGO or community to work with them to register the forms and do it faster.

**Update:**

This patent is kind of idea which have some steps todo and combined of some availble technologies like uber for some optimization in waste management industry.

I can add some electrical inovation to this idea like asked [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/591185/about-using-the-quad-copter-motors-as-power-generator-charging-its-battery-when), but i think it could complicate the review and checking procedure of patents expertise in government institute, and don't want bother them.

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, nothing you have published publicly will be eligible for patenting.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish by pursuing a patent?

Comment: This is one android application with  Some Smart IOT trash Bin with AI Musical capability. I am from iran country, but companies or goverment have not enough responsibility to take it or run it and i lonely dont run it because of waste manamnet mafia and political pressure on environmental activities. So registering as patent give me credibility to be seen or have somthing to give the ptoject to Foreign companies. Also i have two friends which one of them has some hatd time because of me and this project, and i want thanks their helps by registering this patent by theur names.

Comment: A patent is not about acknowledging help or gaining reputation. A patent is about keeping others from using an invention. Should you obtain a patent in the UK, you would gain the ability to stop others from using your invention in the UK and the UK alone. Patents usually take 3 or more years to obtain and cost money. If you are trying to change the world with your invention without financial gain, obtaining a patent is a bad way to do so.

Comment: I have had some respectful feelings about problems I have caused for one of my friends, who was hurt because of protecting me in the hard time doing this project. This project is very big and targets the 1.6 trillion $ waste market, so I am searching for around 7 backup systems for finding investment and running this project, like : 1-working with UNDP (UN Development program), 2-patent registering, 3-connecting with city majors,4- VC and 5- Startup accelators, 6-presenting and pithing in internet social media, 7-presenting in smart cities exhibitions. So I guess some of them would work.

Comment: If you are planning to commercialize your ideas especially internationally, then there is really no alternative to paying an actual patent attorney to pursue your IP. You need more than a patent, you need a patent strategy and strong patents worldwide. You will have to find funds to do this, and government grants, venture capital or angel investors are the traditional first steps to getting sufficient funds.

Answer (score 2):

The UK has a “[green channel](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/patents-accelerated-processing#green-channel)” program to accelerate qualifying patent applications and the USPTO did have a pilot green program that has expired. It also provided no cost accelerated examination.

The new director of the USPTO has recently called for a climate related [acceleration program](https://www.uspto.gov/about-us/news-updates/remarks-uspto-director-kathi-vidal-arpa-e-energy-innovation-summit). These programs do not reduce normal fees.

In the UK, the term "registering" a patent is used synonymous with applying for a patent. Note that in the US patents are not “registered” but applied for. The word registered, in the US, would imply that something is automatically granted, like registration of a car.

Also, from your question it is not clear whether or not you have an invention or a loose collection of ideas. In either case you should probably not make it known outside an understanding of confidentiality before filing an application.